# How to write phone number regular expression

Tags: android, regex

Am developing a mobile application where people can register to user the app by forwarding their phone numbers. The phone number must start with "07". Below is the my code

```
public boolean isPhoneNumber(String s) {
    String pattern = "[0-9]";
    if (s.matches(pattern)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

any ideas about how I proceed from here

Comment: Check various regular expressions on this link : http://regexlib.com/(A(3k11t-l-bx51TbStx_502eQq_kMPKrbAUku29jOowfM7aos6m8LTywGmKyLQ9PvcrjtaYPs4AczP5NXz2h7ZVMCGJSGrq8WHjaHgNAZ4GUc1))/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7

Comment: What about the country prefix? Some users will include it, others won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current expression will allow any string to pass as long as it contains a digit between `0` and `9`.

Instead you need the following expression:

```
^07
```

- `^`: Matches start-of-string.
- `0`: Matches a literal `0`.
- `7`: Matches a literal `7`.

In Java:

```
public boolean isPhoneNumber(String s) {
   String pattern = "^07";
   if (s.matches(pattern)) {
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: how do i write that expression ?? i have tried ^07[0-9] but its not working

Comment: @williamjingo Do you still have any problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Use \d to check if the characters are digits or not. For ex. \d{6} will check that there 6 consequent digits.
Here the code you are looking for:

```
public static boolean isPhoneNumber(String s) {
    String pattern = "^07\\d{6}"; 
    if (s.matches(pattern)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check this out to understand more about regular expressions: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

you could try this: `^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$`

Answer (score 0):

for example it is a 10 digit mobile number you can try below

```
       public static boolean isPhoneNumber(String s) {
       String pattern = "^[0-9]{10}"; 
       if (s.matches(pattern)) {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
       }
```